# Condition for rationality of $\frac{ar + b}{cr + d}$ with $r$ irrational

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r$ be an irrational number. What conditions must $a, b, c, d$ satisfy so that $\cfrac{ar + b}{cr + d}$ is rational?

I got as far as putting it in a reduced form:

$\cfrac{ar + b}{cr + d} = \cfrac{p}{q}$ with $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, but that didn't lead me anywhere. I'm sure I must be missing something trivial, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you thought, let

$$\frac{ar+b}{cr+d}=h\implies ar+b=hcr+hd\implies (a-hc)r=hd-b$$

Now, if $h$ is rational then it is also $a-hc$ and $hd-b$, thus the unique  set of solutions that make the fraction rational are that $a=hc$ and $b=hd$ for some arbitrary $h\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I don't quite understand that $(a - hc)r = hd - b$ leads to $a = hc$ and $b = hd$. Is it because a rational over a rational is rational as well, thus we must have $(a - hc) = 0$ and $hd - b = 0$, otherwise $r$ wouldn't be irrational?

Also, the conditions $a = hc$ and $b = hd$ are equivalent to $\cfrac{a}{c} - \cfrac{b}{d} = 0 \Rightarrow ad - bc = 0$, right?

EDIT: Oh yeah, that's exactly it. Thanks!

Comment: let $p:=a-hc$ and $q:=hd-b$. Then if $h\in\Bbb Q$ then $p,q\in\Bbb Q$ also, what would imply, by the equation $pr=q$, that $pr$ is also rational. But the unique way that $pr$ can be rational is if $p=0$, in any other case $pr$ will be irrational. In other words: the unique way to multiply a rational and an irrational an get a rational is that the rational will be zero.

Comment: proof for the last fact: if $p\neq 0$ then $pr=q\implies r=\frac{q}p$ but $\frac{q}p\in\Bbb Q$, what is a contradiction.